# make header go and stay at the top of page

Tags: html, css, header

my header is currently in the middle of the page..
any suggestions to make it stay at the top?

```
`header {
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
}



<!--body { display: flex; justify-content: center; align-items: center; }
h1 {font-family: sans-serif;} 
h1 {text-align: centre;} 
-->

</style>
</head>
<body>
<h1><a href="https://w1545565.users.ecs.berries.ac.uk/webDev/one.html"> Site Map </a>
  </h1>

<hr>`
```

Comment: `position: sticky` will only start showing its effect once you scroll. You may not have enough content for that at the moment. You can use `position: fixed` if you want it attached to the top

Comment: here - `align-items: center;`, but show more code pls

Comment: There is no `<header>` in your HTML.

Answer (score 0):

You should apply the css property "position" with a value of "fixed". Look at the code snippet below (copied from w3schools, read about it [here](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_fixed_menu.asp)):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
body {margin:0;}

.navbar {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.navbar a {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
}

.navbar a:hover {
  background: #ddd;
  color: black;
}

.main {
  padding: 16px;
  margin-top: 30px;
  height: 1500px; /* Used in this example to enable scrolling */
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="navbar">
  <a href="#home">Home</a>
  <a href="#news">News</a>
  <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
</div>

<div class="main">
  <h1>Fixed Top Menu</h1>
  <h2>Scroll this page to see the effect</h2>
  <h2>The navigation bar will stay at the top of the page while scrolling</h2>

  <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
  <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
  <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
  <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
  <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
  <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
  <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
  <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
  <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
  <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
  <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
  <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
  <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
  <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
  <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
  <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
  <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
  <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
  <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
  <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```